# Result of zabbix_get is contacting,why?

Tags: zabbix

i use zabbix 3.4 to monitor zookeeper role,so i write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
role=$(sh /usr/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status| cut -d" " -f2)
echo $role
```

then I add *UserParameter=zkrole,sudo sh /root/checkZKrole.sh* in zabbix_agentd.conf and restart zabbix-agent,but when i use zabbix_get to check my job,the result of zabbix-get is "contacting",why and how to fix it?help me please!

```
[root@dahuatech ~]# zabbix_get -s 172.1.1.28 -k zkrole
contacting
[root@dahuatech ~]# zabbix_get -s 172.1.1.28 -k proc.num[,,,zoo]
1
```

Comment: What is the output of the script when run on 172.1.1.28 itself?

Comment: @L.O.vanIngen i know the reason,because i used "sudo" and zookeeper is running by root,so zabbix account can not get the result correctly,the result of it is "Error contacting service. It is probably not running",so i get "contacting"....